# Insertar valor fijo y valores de un array en tabla intermedia, laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy necesitando insertar en una tabla pivot un dato fijo y otros adicionales, me explico mejor:

Tengo una vista en la cual mediante un select puedo seleccionar un servicio que se le asignara aun tecnico (por ejemplo HFC, FTTH, ETC) pero adicional al que le puedan asignar desde el select, debo insertar un servicio llamado ACTIVOS (que esta en el select igual) por lo cual no se me ocurre de que manera podria hacer que por defecto se inserte el servicio ACTIVOS ademas del otro servicio que puedan seleccionar

El select lo lleno VIA AJAX con datos que vienen de una tabla:

```
$('#empresa').on('change', function(){
        var empresa_id = $(this).val();
        //$('#servicio_id').val('');
        //console.log(empresa_id)
        $('#empresa_id').val(empresa_id);
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('servicio') }}"+`/${empresa_id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    var json = data;
                    //console.log(result.data)
                    var opciones = '';
                    var opciones = '<option value="">--Seleccione Servicio a Asignar--</option>';
                    json.data.forEach(element => {
                        opciones += `<option value="${element.id}">${element.servicio}</option>`;
                    });
                    $("#servicio").html(opciones)
                    //$("#servicio_id").append(opciones);
                 }
            });
```

Y en el controlador el metodo store lo tengo asi:
public function store(Request $request){ //TecnicoStore

```
    //dd($servicios);

    $tecnico = new Tecnico();
    $tecnico->num_doc = $request->num_doc;
    $tecnico->nombre_primario = $request->nombre_primario;
    $tecnico->nombre_secundario = $request->nombre_secundario;
    $tecnico->ape_pat = $request->ape_pat;
    $tecnico->ape_mat = $request->ape_mat;
    $tecnico->sexo = $request->sexo;
    $tecnico->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fecha_nacimiento;
    $tecnico->jefe_directo = $request->jefe_directo;
    $tecnico->direccion = $request->direccion;
    $tecnico->villa_pobl = $request->villa_pobl;
    $tecnico->comuna = $request->comuna;
    $tecnico->fecha_contratacion = $request->fecha_contratacion;
    $tecnico->celular = $request->celular;
    $tecnico->email = $request->email;
    $tecnico->status = $request->status;
    $tecnico->cargo_id = $request->cargo_id;
    $tecnico->empresa_id = $request->empresa_id;
    //$tecnico->servicio_id = $request->servicio_id;
    $tecnico->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $tecnico->save();

  //insertamos en la tabla tecnio_serivios
    //$servicios = [3, $request->servicio];
     $servicio_id = $request->get('servicio_id');
     $servicio_id = [] ;

     //$servicios [] = array(3,$request->servicio);
    $cont = 0;
     while($cont < count ($servicio_id)){
        $tecnico_servicio = new TecnicoServicio();
        $tecnico_servicio->tecnico_id = $tecnico->id;
        //AQUI SE HARIA EL INSERT DE LOS SERVICIOS (ACTIVOS Y EL QUE VENGA DESDE EL SELECT DE LA VISTA)
        $tecnico_servicio->servicio_id= array(3,$request->servicio[$cont]);
         //$detalleIngreso->servicio_id = $servicio_id[$cont];
        $tecnico_servicio->save();
        $cont=$cont+1;
     }

    Alert::success('Registro Añadido con exito!!!', 'El registro del técnico ha sido almacenado con exito...');
    return redirect()->route('admin.tecnicos.index')->with('success','Técnico registrado con exito...');
}
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: @BetaM exacto, hacia esa tabla se debe guardar el tecnico_id y los servicio_id

Comment: estuve intentando con un array pero tampoco me resulto :8

Comment: @BetaM hola, asi es, por ejemplo el servicio_id 3 debe ir obligatoriamente, y el otro servicio es el que se selecciona desde el select, por lo cual obviamente se haria un insert de 2 filas para el mismo tecnico

Comment: actualize el post con el codigo que estoy manejando ahora, Hace el insert en la tabla tecnicos, pero en la pivot (Modelo TecnicoServicio) no inserta nada

Answer (score 0):

Tengo los siguientes comentarios:

1. No veo necesario que debas tener un modelo para tu tabla intermedia, podrás interactuar con la misma con los métodos que Eloquent te proveé
2. Posterior a lo anterior, tus 2 modelos deberían tener las siguientes relaciones declaradas:

Modelo Tecnico:

```
class Tecnico extends Model 
{
    public function servicios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Servicio::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Servicio:

```
class Servicio extends Model 
{
    public function tecnicos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tecnico::class);
    }
}
```

Nota importante:

- Estoy asumiendo que sigues las convenciones de Eloquent respecto al nombre de tablas y llaves foráneas, de no ser así entonces te recomiendo [leas a detalle este apartado](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure) y [este otro](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions).

Los cambios anteriores, te los comento por que considero que la operación que planeas llevar a cabo sería mas fácil mediante [el método **`attach`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) disponible gracias al trait *InteractsWithPivotTable*

Por ejemplo:

- Recién acabas de crear un nuevo técnico de esta forma:

  ```
  $nuevoTecnico = new Tecnico();
  ......................
  ......................
  $nuevoTecnico->save();
  ```

  - En este punto tienes ya acceso a las propiedades del registro, entonces para obtener el id puede ser tan simple como esto:

    ```
    $nuevoTecnico->id;
    ```
- En este punto no se como llegan los ids de los servicios si como un array o son objetos dentro de un array, entonces te coloco el siguiente ejemplo para ilustrar:

  ```
    $servicioUno = 1;
    $servicioDos = 2;

    $arrayServicios = [$servicioUno, $servicioDos];

    $tecnicoIdentificado = $nuevoTecnico->id;

    foreach($arrayServicios as $servicio) {
        $tecnicoIdentificado->servicios()->attach($servicio);
    }
  ```

**Notas finales**

- Con lo anterior se registrarán vinculados a un técnico en específico todos los servicios asociados.
- La forma de iterar los ids de los servicios puede variar en función de como los recibas en tu controlador (*si como arrays o como objetos*)
- Como notas (*considerando que esto claramente tendrá peros y observaciones*) podemos lograr lo mismo pero con una sintaxis un tanto mas organizada